# PyCharm Professional version doesn't support code folding for cdef

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm 2018.1 Professional

The PyCharm editor doesn't allow to code folding either cdef or cpdef. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What is the error shown on `cdef void helloworld`?

Comment: Please vote for the corresponding feature request in PyCharm's bug tracker: [PY-7292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7292).